# Echo variable in json/array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have made a code that works however it doesn't work when I try to echo a variable in the json/array. Can anyone help?

Code that works

```
$data = array("ips" => ["ip" => "1.1.1.1"]);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

Code that doesn't work

```
 $test=1.1.1.1
 $data = array("ips" => ["ip" => "$test"]);                                                                    
 $data_string = json_encode($data);
```

The code just return with 500error on browser

As you can see i am trying to introduce a variable. Can anyone help?

Comment: The error 500 is most likely caused by `$test=1.1.1.1`, the rest of your code is FINE You need to add string quotes around the `$test` variable, such as: `$test = '1.1.1.1'`

Comment: The posted answer is correct. I'll also add that `"$test"` is the same as simply `$test` and the latter looks a lot cleaner. Also you're mixing up styles. `array()` is the old style and `[]` is the newer style. I suggest you stick to one or the other (and the newer style is a lot cleaner). So - `$data = ["ips"=>["ip"=>$test]];`

Comment: put quote around "1.1.1.1"

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in `$test` variable. You can use string type, like this:

```
$test = '1.1.1.1';
$data = array("ips" => ["ip" => "$test"]);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to put quotes around "1.1.1.1", or php's parser doesn't interpret it as a string (which is what it's supposed to be)

DO THIS:

```php
$test="1.1.1.1";
$data = array("ips" => ["ip" => "$test"]);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

NOT THIS:

```php
$test=1.1.1.1
$data = array("ips" => ["ip" => "$test"]);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);
```

Also it's bad practice to mix the shorthand for arrays with the array function, you should either do `array("ips" => array("ip" => "$test"));` or `["ips" => ["ip" => "$test"]];`

Comment: Oh shit, i am so stupid. I was focusing on the $data that i completely missed the first one.

Answer (score 1):

While the right answers are already given:
You have a syntax error there and should write

```
$ip = "1.1.1.1";
```

I would recommend that you first take a look at your server's error logs for the web server and PHP. It will clearly state why your script is failing:

```
[Sat May 16 13:26:20.744739 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1653:tid 140650782840576] [client ::1:55866] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.1' (T_DNUMBER) in /var/www/html/stackoverflow.php on line 2\n', referer: http://localhost/
```

Alternatively you can use `php myScript.php` and run this from the console and get the same error message. Naturally, the possible use of the PHP-CLI depends a bit on the complexity of your script.

This will help yourself in the future to find those errors easier.